# Changing String into Time

Tags: excel, timestamp, string-to-datetime

I need to change String in D column(example 28/10/2018:01:51:29) into Time format.

I've tried: 
            Format cells and make my own formating(dd/mm/yyyy:hh:mm:ss) 
            Data->Text to columns

But neither worked

Comment: If your string is in `D1`, can you try `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(D1,10))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(D1,8))` in a new column?

Comment: I've alredy tried something similar, when y put your formula in new colum pop-up window shows and says there is something wrong with the formula

Comment: Can you share the exact formula you're using? Do all the strings in column D follow the dd/mm/yyyy:hh:mm:ss formatting?

Comment: i've used your formula      `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(D1,10))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(D1,8))`    , yes everything in column D is dd/mm/yyyy (example 28/10/2018:12:04:17)

Comment: What language is your version of Excel in?

Comment: My language is set to Czech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the colon `:` between the date and the time. Try this:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D1,":"," ",1))
```

This will return a number, like `0.077418981` which Excel can interpret as a time if you format the cell as *time*. If you want to skip this step and see the time as a string, use an additional `TEXT` function

```
=TEXT(TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D1,":"," ",1)),"hh:mm:ss")
```

---

In Czech:

```
=ČASHODN(DOSADIT(D1,":"," ",1))
=TEXT(ČASHODN(DOSADIT(D1,":"," ",1)),"hh:mm:ss")
```

You may also need to swap commas `,` for semi-colons `;` if your regional settings require it:

```
=ČASHODN(DOSADIT(D1;":";" ";1))
=TEXT(ČASHODN(DOSADIT(D1;":";" ";1));"hh:mm:ss")
```

[Translations](http://dolf.trieschnigg.nl/excel/index.php?langids=en+cz)

Comment: Am I misreading the question? I understood that OP wanted to maintain the date (28/10/2018) portion as well, based on the comment "make my own formating(dd/mm/yyyy:hh:mm:ss)". Otherwise, good call on the Czech translation and note about semicolons.

Comment: @BigBen, it's not entirely clear. However, the first line seems to be the request. I guessed making his "own formatting" was an attempt to explain to Excel what format his data was in? no idea really.

Comment: However, the SUBSTITUTE function turns his string into a workeable date regardless of where he's ultimately trying to do with it :)

Comment: To clear my question: I needed to convert STRING to TIME(also sorry for unclear question im not native speaker and also not pro in excel) Thank you:)